# Run database connection over multiple files?

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I have many files, and I want to get data from my server by using functions from one file that holds my connection to the database.

Question 1. How do I hold the connection?

```py
def main():
    global mydb
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    database='database',
    host="host",
    user="user",
    password="passwd"
    )
    print("Started database connection")
    return mydb
main()
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

This is my current solution to holding the database connection to my server, it doesn't work but from my research that's how far I've come.

The database.py file includes functions that updates and gets information from the database.
I know how to import these functions but I don't know how to start or hold the database connection, help?

Comment: The files you have are Python scripts? And you want to use the connection established from `database.py` file from those scripts?

Comment: Yes the files I have is python scripts, I wish to use functions I already have in `database.py` in other files which I have accomplished. I just don't know how to start the connection in `database.py`, don't know how to keep the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Data Access Object (DAO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) pattern, how about to use class?

`database.py`:

```
class DB:
    def __del__(self):
        self.mydb.close()

    def __init__(self):
        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            database='database',
            host="host",
            user="user",
            password="passwd"
        )
        print("Started database connection")

    def do_this_with_connection(self):
        mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
        ....
        mycursor.close()

    def do_that_with_connection(self):
        mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
        ....
        mycursor.close()
```

From another file, you can do

```
from database import DB

DB().do_this_with_connection()
DB().do_that_with_connection()
```

When `DB` instance is `__init__`iated, a connection is automatically established and it is (also automatically) `close`ed when `__del__`eted. In this way, you can forget about connection and do what you something on a database.

Comment: But isn't it stupid to re-open a connection for every time something happens? And what if I receive another request at the same one another one is being handled? That will conflict as I can only hold 1 connection unless I'm pool~ing

Comment: You can keep DAO instantiated by `DB()` as long as you wish. Also, since SQLite does not support table lock, it locks an entire DB when writing. So, if you have to write many times, you should close and reconnect connections often to make read operations still work. Based on this approach, try to find the best solution for your situation.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you.